# Tool to mine plastic scm data

Tags: plasticscm

Is there any external tool to mine plastic scm data. I have a requirement to figure out hot spots in my projects which go through frequent changes? if not, is it possible to query this information in a structural way from Plastic SCM itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any external tools to mine the Plastic SCM data but depending on your needs I'm almost sure you can use the "cm find" command in order to get what you need.

The "cm find" command provides a very flexible way to extract Plastic SCM information from the repository, here you have a guide plenty of examples: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/cmfind/plastic-scm-version-control-query-system-guide.shtml

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, as @mrcatacroquer said, it is possible to find the files with more revisions on a given period, simply with cm find revision, and dumping the results to excel, then calculating and grouping there. If the hot spots are files too frequently changed, you have a good hint with that.